# migration of data appending boolean flag fields for a multilist dropdown

Tags: sql, boolean, migration, append

I am preparing a migration script whereby the values from one system that has multiple boolean values will be mapped to a multi-select list in the new system and I have been asked to retrieve data from the old system in the format. Each value has been assigned a mapping in the new system. so for instance flag 1 is true in the old system the requirements value will need '0001' appended to a string value, this should iterate through each of the required flag fields so the output for each customer is as follows

- '0001','0002','0003'
- '0002'
- '0001','0003'

My account table has the following values flag1, flag2, flag3, flag4 and flag 5 so to retrieve the raw information I just use

```
select id, flag1, flag2, flag3, flag4 from account
```

How can I iterate through the relevant fields so that I can return a string in the aforementioned fashion? Would this be best to be done via a series of IF statements on the query?

For instance some sample data:

```
id   flag1   flag2   flag3   flag4
1    true    false   false   true
2    true    true    true    true
3    false   true    false   false
4    true    false   false   false
5    false   false   false   false
```

I would like to receive output as follows:

```
id   string
1    '0001','0004'
2    '0001','0002','0003','0004'
3    '0002'
4    '0001'
5
```

Comment: Please provide some data and the desired output to help us better understand what you want.

Comment: I have added some sample data and outcome that I had hoped to find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    id
    ,(case when flag1 = 'true' then ',''0001''' else '' end)
    + (case when flag2 = 'true' then ',''0002''' else '' end)
    + (case when flag3 = 'true' then ',''0003''' else '' end)
    + (case when flag4 = 'true' then ',''0004''' else '' end)
FROM account
```

UPDATE:
Because the first flag might be false and you don't want a leading ',' you can eliminate it by using `STUFF()`

```
SELECT 
    id
    ,STUFF(((case when flag1 = 'true' then ',''0001''' else '' end)
    + (case when flag2 = 'true' then ',''0002''' else '' end)
    + (case when flag3 = 'true' then ',''0003''' else '' end)
    + (case when flag4 = 'true' then ',''0004''' else '' end)
    ),1,1,'')
FROM account
```

Comment: I have tried using this with the rest of my query but I am receiving syntax error that stuff must contain 4 arguments

Comment: SELECT a.AccountId as 'ref_id', 
 STUFF((case when b.New_VisuallyImpaired = 'true' then ',''0001''' else '' end)
    + (case when b.New_SpeechImpaired = 'true' then ',''0002''' else '' end)
    + (case when b.New_HearingImpaired = 'true' then ',''0003''' else '' end)
    + (case when b.New_Elderly = 'true' then ',''0004''' else '' end)),1,1,''))
  FROM AccountBase as a
  inner join AccountExtensionBase as b ON a.AccountId = b.AccountId
  inner join CustomerAddressBase as c ON a.AccountId = c.ParentId
  where new_accountstage = 7
  and new_accounttype = 2
  and addresstypecode is null

Comment: I missed a parenthesis at the beginning of STUFF :)

Comment: Thanks Kostis greatly appreciate that worked a treat

Comment: I need to wrap the code in ^^ and not '' will his affect it

Comment: No..just be careful with the extra apostrophes we used to escape ' inside quotes. For the ^ you can use it normally without escaping

Comment: trying this now

Comment: Glad I helped! :)